# glob works on local server, empty on remote

Tags: php, glob

My `glob` function is doing what it's supposed when I run the script locally on a test server, but when I run the function on my remote host I get a blank array.

```
$folderDir = '*/';
$folders = glob($folderDir, GLOB_ONLYDIR);

echo json_encode($folders);
```

I set MAMP to the same version (5.2.17) to see if that was the problem, but it still works fine there.

Comment: are there any subdirs on your remote host?

Comment: What would that do exactly? Pardon me if I'm being simple.

Comment: well, if you don't get results from your remote server with the exact same code, then something's different. e.g. the director you're running this in on the remote box doesn't have any subdirs, and since you're telling glob to match ONLY directories, no subdirectories = no matches.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. So this script is not working no matter where it is placed in my file structure. The directory is exactly the same on both my computer and the server. Which is to say, I have my whole site loaded and none of it works because this script isn't working, even though the two are almost exactly the same.

Comment: Sorry @MarcB, so yes, the answer is there are indeed sub-directories.

Comment: Also I checked if said sub-directories `is_readable` and they are.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like the server PHP didn't like the `/` after the `*` in my `$folderDir` function. Waste of 7 hours to figure that out, and then some to fix the rest of my code to accommodate for this affecting my other arrays down the line. HOORAY! If anyone knows why this is, I'd love to know why.